# Communicating with remote servers in XD plugins

Tags: javascript, remote-server, adobe-xd

I'm trying to build an XD plugin and wanted to retrieve images from a remote server. Would this be possible? If so, what APIs can I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely! The Adobe XD plugin environment provides standards-compliant implementations of [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/uxp/class/XMLHttpRequest.html), [`WebSocket`](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/uxp/class/WebSocket.html) and [`fetch`](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/uxp/function/fetch.html) APIs. See the [Network I/O documentation](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/uxp/network-index.html) for more information regarding what is and isn't supported.

For an example of how to use `XHR` in your plugin, see the [How to make network requests tutorial](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/tutorials/how-to-make-network-requests/).

For your particular use case, you should check out the [Adobe Stock Photo Search](https://github.com/AdobeXD/plugin-samples/tree/master/e2e-adobe-stock) example  in the [Samples](https://github.com/AdobeXD/plugin-samples) repository.

Depending on what you need to do to the image, you may also need to use some of the [Storage APIs](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/uxp/storage-index.html).